# Книги для изучения Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, книги

Уже довольно давно интересуюсь ЯП Ruby и его многочисленными фреймворками, но в силу занятости над одни проектом возможности начать изучение не было. Но вот проект завершен, время и желание есть, но тут же столкнулся с большой проблемой. Rub` развивается довольно таки быстро, а книг по нему не так много. На данный момент верхняя версия Ruby 2.0.0 и Rails 4.0. Все, что я смог найти более менее адекватное (отзывы, качество, содержание) это Флэнаган Д., Мацумото Ю. - Язык программирования Ruby (Ruby 1.8.7) и Руби С., Томас Д., Хэнссон Д. - Гибкая разработка веб-приложений в среде Rails. 4-е изд. (Rails 3.1). Как видно расхождение нынешней ветки языка и то, чему учат в книгах - довольно большое. Отсюда встает вопрос - насколько это существенно и сильно ли это скажется в последствии? А так же, есть ли какие то более "свежие" книги, либо документация. Книги на английском осилить могу, но не с небольшими трудностями, но если другого варианта нет - тогда придется.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хотелось бы отметить, что в книге "Флэнаган Д., Мацумото Ю. - Язык программирования Ruby" обзор 1.8.7 и 1.9.2 версий ruby, я всегда рекомендую эту книгу для начинающего. Ruby версии 2.0 отличается совсем незначительно, по крайней мере на данный момент. Список изменений можете посмотреть [здесь](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/). В Rails 4 изменений относительно rails 3 побольше, но список тоже вполне обозрим - смотрите [здесь](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/11/13/rails-4-compilation-links/).

Ну а вообще, я не уверен, что новичку требуется знание ruby на экстра уровне. На мой взгляд, вам должно вполне хватить вышеописанной книги 'Язык программирования Ruby' и [доков](http://ruby-doc.org/). И поскорее переходить к rails. Для новичка - [railstutrial.ru](http://railstutorial.ru/), потом - [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). Далее предлагаю делать свой проект, читать какой-нибудь 'Rails 3 way'.

Answer (score 6):

[The Rails 4 Way](https://leanpub.com/tr4w)
[Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0 (4th edition): The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0)
[Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1934356166/?tag=stackoverfl08-20)
[Eloquent Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/Eloquent-Ruby-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Series/dp/0321584104/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y)

Все книги конечно же на английском. Русской нормальной литературы по `Ruby/Rails` очень мало. 
Разве что, еще могу посоветовать сайт [`RusRails`](http://rusrails.ru), там выложены переводы официального руководства по `Rails`.

Answer (score 4):

[why_'s poingnant guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) и Well Grounded Rubyist вам в помощь.
Скажется впоследствии? На чём? Есть же rdoc, сидите и читайте что нового в языке и Rails.

Comment: +1 за why_'s poingnant guide to ruby

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь http://www.rubyinside.com/media/poignant-guide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Литература по Ruby в русской локализации выходит с сильным опозданием. Многое не переводится вообще. Так что, чтобы успевать за bleeding edge, стоит все-таки взяться за оригиналы. Помимо упомянутых [[@pirj](/users/8513/pirj)](/users/8513/pirj) книг непременно посмотрите [Ruby Science](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/13-ruby-science), [Multitenancy with Rails](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails) и [Kestrels, Quirky Birds, and Hopeless Egocentricity](https://leanpub.com/combinators).

Рекомендую попробовать курсы от [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/ru/tracks/ruby) и особливо [Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/courses#all).

Answer (score 0):

А есть еще Ruby Warrior: https://www.bloc.io/ruby-warrior/ Хорошая обучающая игра для новичков